# Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, boxplot, statistical-test

I am trying to draw a simple boxplot of viral load and trial arm, but keep getting this error "Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator".

dataset

```
PatientID  trial_arm   viral_load 
1          club        19
2          clinic      19
3          club        19
4          club        64
5          clinic      32
6          clinic      29
7          clinic      92
8          club        19
9          clinic      19
10         club        27
```

When I run the code :

```
> boxplot(dataset,viral_load~trial_arm)
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The trial_arm variable is set as a factor and viral_load is numeric.

Comment: `boxplot(viral_load ~ trial_arm, dataset)`. You have to state the arguments in the right order, see `?boxplot`.

Answer (score 5):

That also happened to me, but then I realized I was putting the response variable and the predictor in the wrong order.

boxplot(response ~ predictor, data = dataset)

Answer (score 0):

The solution by jay.sf in the comment works. You would also need to use `ggplot()` when running your code to produce the boxplot, ie `ggplot() + boxplot(viral_load ~ trial_arm, dataset)`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I had the same problem and I solved this problem by swapping the variables and solving this by putting the "$" sign. I took the int variable first then ~ and in the end, I took the string variable.
so in your case, it would be `boxplot(dataset$viral_load ~ dataset$trial_arm)`

```
library(readxl)
employee_data <- read_excel("Employee.xls", 
                            sheet = "Employee data", col_types = c("numeric", 
                                                                   "text", "date", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                                   "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
View(employee_data)
str(employee_data)

head(employee_data)
tail(employee_data)
plot(employee_data)
#Same variable function
boxplot(employee_data$ID,employee_data$Salary)
#different variable function
boxplot(employee_data$Salary ~ employee_data$Gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem that created this error was that I am using a European format for the data file, which therefore had comma separated decimals instead of dot separated. After replacing the comma's with dots everything was fine.