# Creating a Boxplot for a given variable

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data set from Zillow.

```
train <- read.csv("train.data.csv")
```

I found the 3 zipcodes with the largest mean price of house.

```
train$zipcode <- as.factor(train$zipcode)
l<-tapply(train$price, train$zip, mean)
sort(l,decreasing = TRUE)
```

Which gave me 98039,98004 and 98040. I want to create 3 boxplots of the price for these 3 variables. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you data is like `df` below. With one variable for prices and one for zip codes below `df$price` and `df$zip`.

You can use the base r `boxplot` function. And you can use the `dplyr` `filter` function to filter out these 3 zip codes of interest.

```r
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(price=sample(1:100,20,replace = TRUE),
              zip=c("zip1","zip1","zip1","zip1",
                    "zip2","zip2","zip2","zip2",
                    "98039","98039","98039","98039",
                    "98004","98004","98004","98004",
                    "98040","98040","98040","98040"))
head(df,4)
#>   price  zip
#> 1    36 zip1
#> 2    16 zip1
#> 3    11 zip1
#> 4    89 zip1
df%>%
  filter(zip %in% c("98039","98004","98040"))%>%
  boxplot(price~zip , data=.)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think there are like 200 different zip codes, would I just creat a new matrix with just those zips and their prices?

Comment: no need for matrix you data frame train is good ``boxplot(price~zip , data=train)`` but you will have 200 boxes, try to group the zip into 10 groups (regions)

Comment: That would just plot all 200ish zipcodes when I just want the 3 I listed.

Comment: you can add a ``dplyr`` ``filter`` for that see the updated code

Comment: plz click on the check signe to accept the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I keep on getting an error `Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: could you provide a link to your data ?

Comment: is your error like this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622469/error-in-xfloord-xceilingd-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator